# getc function produce segfault

Tags: c, linux, pointers, unix

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *f_gets(char *s, int n, FILE *iop)
{
    int c=0;
    char *cs;
    cs = s;

    while (--n > 0 && (c = getc(iop)) != EOF)
    {
        if ((*cs++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    }
    *cs = '\0';
    return (c == EOF && cs == s) ? NULL : s;
}


main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char s2[100],s1[100];
    if (argc <= 2 )
        printf("2 argument needed \n"); 
    else
        if((fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r"))== NULL && (fp2=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL)
            printf("cat: can't open The file\n");
        else
        {
            while(1)
            {
                f_gets(s1,100,fp1); // 1st iteration
                f_gets(s2,100,fp2); // 2nd iteration
                if(!strcmp(s1,s2)) 
                    printf("%s %s",s1,s2);
            }
            fclose(fp1);
            fclose(fp2);
        }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out a b
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

In the above program, the segfault occurs when we call the f_gets at second time. Even I twice check the program it is hard to
find the problem. Does any one explain why it produce the problem .

Answer (score 8):

Your second file is not open at the time when you make the call.

The problem is that you are calling `fopen` from the path with short circuiting:

```
if((fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r"))== NULL && (fp2=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL)
```

Because of a mistake in your code, when `fp1` opens fine, `fp2` will always remain closed. This is because `(fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r"))== NULL` will evaluate to `0`, and ensure that `(fp2=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL` will never be called.

You could fix this by replacing `&&` with `||`, but a better approach would be opening one file at a time.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r"))== NULL && (fp2=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL)
```

means, "if the program failed to open both fp1 and fp2". You could solve this by using `||` instead. But preferably don't write long and complex expressions, since they add nothing but an increased chance of writing bugs.

Instead, do this:

```
fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(fp1 == NULL)
{
  // error handling
}

fp2=fopen(argv[2],"r");
if(fp2 == NULL)
{
  fclose(fp1);
  // error handling
}
```

And as a bonus: just because we re-wrote the program into something readable, we now also spotted a second bug. In case the program opened fp1 but failed to open fp2, it never closed fp1 before aborting.